# System.DBNull error

Tags: c#

How can I resolve this problem ?why image file making system.dbnull error?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Categories", baglantiYolu);
        DataTable tablo = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(tablo);
        foreach (DataRow kategori in tablo.Rows)
        {
            Kategori k = new Kategori();
            k.KategoriID = int.Parse(kategori["CategoryID"].ToString());
            k.KategoriAdı = kategori["CategoryName"].ToString();
            k.UrunSayisi = UrunSayisiniGetir(int.Parse(kategori["CategoryID"].ToString()));
            k.Aciklama = kategori["Description"].ToString();
            k.Resim = (byte[])kategori["Picture"];
            listBoxKategoriler.Items.Add(k);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for DBNull before casting:

```
if( kategorie["Picture"] != DBNull.Value ) k.Resim = (Byte[])kategorie["Picture"];
```

Comment: thanks for your help David it is solved when i add the statement that you sent. your and Adam's code refers to the same point i think. thus i also accepted his solution.

Answer (score 3):

If the return value from the database for that column is `NULL`, this translates to `DBNull.Value` in code.

You need to check for this as it won't successfully cast to `byte[]`. Something like this:

```
object val = row["Pictire"];

if (val == DBNull.Value || val == null)
{
    k.Resim = new byte[0];
}
else
{
    k.Resim = (byte[])val;
}
```

You will need to do similar checks for all potentially null columns.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you don't have an image, but that field is empty (null).
You cannot cast a dbnull value to something else.
You first have to check if is null and if not read it converting into `byte[]`.

```
object pict = kategori["Picture"];
k.Resim =  (pict == DBNull.Value) ? new byte[0] : (byte[])pict;
```

Comment: this is an exercise that I found on net.In Nortwind I think it is in images

Comment: @modestandcutegirl: taht doesn't mean it's correct :) Check if fiels is dbnull and only if it's not cast as you please.

Comment: thanks for replying Marco. its solved. i think all solutions refer to the same point that is missed.

Comment: thanks for replying Marco. its solved. i think all solutions refer to the same point that is missed. –